# Using operators & | on enums in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum in my application to represent the saving options where the user can save the image with lines drawn, circles, rectangles or any combination, so I declared an enum to represent the saving option.

```
enum SaveOption{lines,circles,rectangles};
```

How can I use operators to;

- Add option to the options
- Remove option from the options

Comment: I noticed that some people use |= to add option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mark the enum with the `[Flags]` attribute, and give each possible value a unique bit value:

```
[Flags]
enum SaveOption
{
    lines = 0x1,
    circles = 0x2,
    rectangles = 0x4
}
```

Then you can do this sort of thing:

```
SaveOption options;

option = SaveOption.lines | SaveOption.circles; // lines + circles
option |= SaveOptions.rectangles; // now includes rectangles
option &= ~SaveOptions.circles; // now excludes circles
```

Finally for ref, each option must have a value that is represented by a single bit, so in hex that's `0x1`, `0x2`, `0x4`, `0x8`, then `0x10`, `0x20`, `0x40`, `0x80` etc.  Which is easier to remember than 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536.  Which is as far as I remember :)

Comment: My post explains how to do that.. to add, use `|=` to remove, use `&= ~`.

Comment: Oh my... You get my +1 for the extended answer. I'm too lazy too write so much ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you'd need to specify values which worked in a bitwise fashion. You'd also be best to decorate the enum with [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx). Following naming conventions, you'd also rename it to be plural. You'd end up with:

```
[Flags]
enum SaveOptions
{
    None = 0,
    Lines = 1,
    Circles = 2,
    Rectangles = 4
}
```

You can then do:

```
SaveOptions foo = SaveOptions.Lines | SaveOptions.Rectangles;
```

and similar bitwise operations.

The `FlagsAttribute` will change how the enum values are converted to and from strings. It's not actually *required* in order to get the bitwise operations to work, but it's definitely a strong convention, and a generally good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Flags attribute. Don't forget to specify unique bitwise values for each member of the enum:

```
[Flags]
enum SaveOption
{
    lines = 1,
    circles = 2,
    rectangles = 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a cast:

```
(SaveOption) (lines | circles)
```

or

```
SaveOption option = (SaveOption) (lines | circles);

(SaveOption) ((option & ~lines) | rectangle)
```

You also need to assign bit values to the enum members (as in some of the other answers).

Note: I've left off some C# syntax, and this applies to .Net 2, later version may have cleaned up this syntax.

Comment: Actually, that may be C++/CLI syntax. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

As for manipulating the flags;

```
[Flags]
public enum SaveOption
{
    Lines = 1,
    Circles = 2,
    Rectangles = 4
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SaveOption option = SaveOption.Circles | SaveOption.Rectangles;

    Console.WriteLine( option );

    option -= SaveOption.Circles;

    Console.WriteLine( option );

    option = option | SaveOption.Lines;

    Console.WriteLine(option);
}
```

Comment: Yep.  to see add; option &= ~SaveOption.Rectangles;

            Console.WriteLine(option);